# Angular 4 not working with Shape of Semantic Ui

Tags: angular, semantic-ui

I have a problem with the compatibility with Angular 4 and Semantic ui. I use the module Shape and it works but the design of the transition is different.
I use mdbootstrap too, but even if I remove it it's the same.

Do you know how to make compatible semantic ui with angular 4 ?

Thank you

Comment: what exactly is happening ?can you post some code and screenshots of what exactly is happening ...

Comment: I find the problem, the conflict was not between bootstrap and semantic ui. But between Material design lite and semantic ui.

Comment: why are you using so many ui frameworks together !!!

Comment: Because I tried Bootstrap with Material design lite, but I had some conflicts. So I tried mdbootstrap but he has 2 plans : one free and one pro (of course the pro is expansive). So I wanted to continue to use material design lite and bootsrap.